# Pivot issue in databricks

Tags: azure, databricks

I have dataframe table having values :

```
id      Country               Interest
00    Russian         Digestion;Destillation
```

I want to pivot the Interest column and name new column in azure databricks in python like this    :

```
id    Country     Int                  Interest
00Q7  Russ        Digestion            Digestion;Destillation
00Q7  Russ        Destillation         Digestion;Destillation
```

Please advise how it can be done

Regards
RK

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample dataframe similar to yours using the following code:

```
data = [['00Q7','Russian Federation','Digestion;Destillation'],['00Q6','United States','Oils;Automobiles']]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema = ['id','country','interests'])
display(df)
```

[image]

- To get the desired output (like yours), first I have split the data in `interests` column using `pyspark.sql.functions.split`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split,col
 
df1 = df.withColumn("interest", split(col("interests"), ";"))
display(df1)
```

[image]

- Now I have exploded the new column `interest` using `pyspark.sql.functions.explode` to get the required output.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
op  = df1.withColumn('interest',explode(col('interest')))
display(op)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
data = [['00Q7','Russian Federation','01_Digestion;02_Destillation']]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema = ['id','country','interests'])
#display(df)

from pyspark.sql.functions import split,col
df1 = df.withColumn("interest", split(col("interests"), ";"))

from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
op  = df1.withColumn('interest',explode(col('interest')))

#UPDATE
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat,lit

op.withColumn("set",concat(lit('Set'),split(col('interest'),'_').getItem(0))).show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

**UPDATE-2:**

```
pdf['set']= pdf['interest'].str.split('_').str[0]

import numpy as np
pdf["set"] = np.where(pdf["set"].astype(int)<10 , 'Set'+pdf['set'].str[1], 'Set'+pdf['set'])
```

Comment: id      Country               Interest
00    Russian         01_Digestion;02_Destillation
I want to pivot the Interest column in azure databricks in python like this and need to create a new column with name set and trim only the number values:

id    Country     Int                          Interest                             Set
00Q7  Russ        Digestion            Digestion;Destillation         Set01
00Q7  Russ        Destillation         Digestion;Destillation         Set02

Comment: Current :
id      Country          Interest                           Interest            
00    Russ           01_Digestion;02_Destillation        01_Digestion          
00    Russ           01_Digestion;02_Destillation        02_Destillation     
Looking in this type of result
FinalResult :
id      Country          Interest                           Interest            Set
00    Russ          01_Digestion;02_Destillation        01_Digestion        Set01  
00    Russ          01_Digestion;02_Destillation        02_Destillation     Set02

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check if it is your requirement. If you want the interest column value as `01_digestion`, you can remove the 2nd with column part (where I split and used getItem(1)).

Comment: But in display in set column as Set01,Set02

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: And one more column need to add for this dataframe as SourceSystem and the value will be hardcoded as Salesforce

Comment: You can simply use `op = op.withColumn('SourceSystem',lit('Salesforce'))`. To add any new column you can use `withColumn`. If there are any additional blockers, please open a new thread (since the query here is solved) with the code you have tried and any errors that you are facing so that the community will be able to assist you.

Comment: the above set column as set01 and set02 how it can be done in pandas dataframe and not able to see the column as Set

Comment: I am using the below query
S_Silver['Set'] = S_Silver['SingleSet'].str.split('_')

The column is appearing like this 
Set
["01","Laboratory","Rotavapor"]
["07","Chromatography"]
["08","Destillation"]

How the above query can be manipulated
Actual Result
Set
Set01
Set07
Set08

Comment: This query is appearing the correct value

S_Silver['Set'] = S_Silver['SingleSet'].str.split('_').str[0]

But i need to mention as "Set" how it can be done in the query

Comment: You can use pdf['set']= 'Set'+pdf['interest'].str.split('_').str[0]

Comment: Where i need to go and mark it is as answer

Comment: and one more requirement came up to remove 0 values in  Set column Set01 wanted result as Set 1

Comment: Are there set values greater that 10? like is there a set10 and set11 value present in your data?

Comment: yes if 0 values tappear first hen it must not display

Comment: one more column i need to create as check and if the set  column has value then must display Set otherwise it is blank then Unset how it can be done with above data frame